# MongoDB create unique field but not indexed?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

Is there any option by which in Mongo I can make the field as `unique`, but do not `index` it, because as every index occupies some space as well as causes an overhead on each insert, update and delete, and as I am rarely going to use this field for read operations, that's why I only want to restrict uniqueness but do not want any performance gain by using indexing.

Comment: How do you expect MongoDB to ensure field uniqueness without an index? The only alternative is to perform a full collection scan on every insert and update operation, which will cause an insane overhead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no way and no reason to do that. What do you mean by

> overhead on each insert, update and delete

That overhead comes from unique constraint, not because of the indexes.

> every index occupies some space

Yeah, of course, it takes some space to store indexes in HDD or SSD, but as long as you don't do `read/query`, it will not affect the performance of another operations.

Read more: [MongoDB Internal implementation of indexing ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41407549/mongodb-internal-implementation-of-indexing)

Comment: So, adding index only takes some space on disk, or it also store all of them in memory(decrease main meory which makes mongo slow?)? Does it have any performance issue on insert/update of docs.

Comment: @SudhanshuGaur the index will be in loaded in memory because the uniqueness needs to be checked on each operation, it'd be *slower* if it weren't in memory.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use a custom value for the `_id` field, which is:

- required to be present in every document
- required to have a unique value within a collection
- indexed by default

In the [Field Names](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#field-names) section:

> The field name _id is reserved for use as a primary key; its value must be unique in the collection, is immutable, and may be of any type other than an array.

If you don't provide an `_id` field when you insert a document, MongoDB will create one for you using [ObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/).

If your requirement mandates the use of a unique constraint and you don't want to create an extra index to enforce uniqueness, just use the `_id` field.